# Can the pointer dereferencing sign * be called "many"?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I saw that pointer to either a single variable or an array in C is declared and printed using the same syntax. So I thought of `*` to be called `many` like in regular expression sign * which means many such as x*=xxx....

```
int a[3] = { 4, 5, 6 };
int b = 3;

int *p, *q; // same syntax for either single variable or array
p = a; // pointer to many int
q = &b; // pointer to an int
printf("%d %d", *p, *q); // same syntax again
```

So can I call both p and q as `pointer to many int` for ease of understanding?

Comment: As you already notices, q for example is a pointer to _one_ int. So "many" doesn't seem an appropriate name for the pointer type or dereference operator, correct?

Comment: Technically it is pointer to a single int only (first element in case of array). Since the elements in the array are stored in contiguous memory locations, remaining elements are accessible from the first one. The pointer, at any instance, still points to a single int only.

Comment: p is not a pointer to many ints. it is still only a pointer to one int. the fact that additional ints are allocated to contiguous addresses after it is not "known" by p. it is something separate that you are responsible for managing.

Comment: Technically, at the time of declaration (`int *p, *q;`), `p` and `q` are variables with an undefined value that may or may not point to an actual memory location. The decision, whether the pointer will ever point to any valid element (let alone 1 or many) is only made at the time when the pointer variable is initialized or re-assigned and the meaning of the pointer can change later if the pointer persists its value while the pointed to memory location is released. Don't worry, pointers are not an easy topic, but you can do it if you keep studying and asking.

Comment: additionally, the `*` in regular expressions also does not mean "many" - it means "0 or more"

Answer (score 5):

No, that's not a good idea. A pointer can only point to a single variable, although that is often the first element of an array. `p = a;` is the pointer to the first element in the array `a`, and only to that one. The pointer in itself can't know if there's more valid data following the address it is currently pointing at.

For example, it's not meaningful to write a function like `void print_array(int* p)` since that function won't know the size of the array, since `p` only points at the first element. We would rather write something like `void print_array(int* p, int size)`

---

Advanced topic (ignore if beginner): A pointer to "many int" would rather be the more exotic feature called "array pointer", such as `int (*)[3] = &a;`. You can think of this as "a pointer to the whole array" rather than just to the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not really, the types are not *interchangeable*.

While used as the RHS of assignment (among many other cases), a variable with type array decays to the type of pointer to the first element of the array.<sup>note</sup>

So,

```
p = a;
```

is the same as

```
p = &(a[0]);
```

where both the sides are of type pointer to integer (`int *`).

---

NOTE:

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]